# Is there way to make lightning-tabset scrollable?

Tags: lightning-web-components, tab, lightning-tabset

So I have a vertical lightning-tablet and I wanted to make lightning-tabs  scrollable when there are to many of them. Is that possible?

Comment: Can you be more descriptive? You want what to be scrollable? The tabs? The content? The entire component?

Comment: I wanted to scroll the lightning-tabs when there are to many of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to **scroll** the lightning-tabs with `<lightning-tabset variant="vertical">`.

If you want to achieve this I would suggest you go with **[Vertical Tabs](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/vertical-tabs/)** and
**[SLDS Scrollable](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/scrollable/)**

It will be a little hard to implement, however you will be have more control under than UI elements.

So you need to add `slds-scrollable_y` class to
`<ul class="slds-vertical-tabs__nav" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">` line.

Also you can use `template for:each` here to show many lightning tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Limited height should force scroll. If not add also `overflow-y: scroll;`

```html
<template>
    <div style="height: 300px">
        <lightning-tabset variant="vertical">
            <lightning-tab label="Item"> Content ! </lightning-tab>
            <lightning-tab label="Item"> Content ! </lightning-tab>
            <lightning-tab label="Item"> Content ! </lightning-tab>
            <lightning-tab label="Item"> Content ! </lightning-tab>
            <lightning-tab label="Item"> Content ! </lightning-tab>
            <lightning-tab label="Item"> Content ! </lightning-tab>
            <lightning-tab label="Item"> Content ! </lightning-tab>
            <lightning-tab label="Item"> Content ! </lightning-tab>
            <lightning-tab label="Item"> Content ! </lightning-tab>
        </lightning-tabset>
    </div>
</template>
```

Move inline style to the separated CSS class.

Answer (score 0):

What about `variant="scoped"`?

```html
<template>
    <lightning-tabset variant="scoped">
        <template for:each={tabs} for:item="tab">
            <lightning-tab label={tab.label} key={tab.value} value={tab.value}>
                {tab.content}
            </lightning-tab>
        </template>
    </lightning-tabset>
</template>
```

[image]

Resources:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tabset/example

Comment: You can't use the "scoped" and "vertical" variants at the same time. 
And the "scoped" variant will not allow a user to scroll all tabs.

Comment: Yep. I am not suggesting using both at the same time. :) 
Rather try to use `scope` instead of adding scroll. Maybe it will fit you @SBN?

Comment: The problem is that I need to make vertical tabs scrollable